# sqlite3-ruby compilation and sqlite3 packaging for a rails app

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

We are currently trying to package sqlite3 and sqlite3-ruby with an application that will be released as open source (ruby/rails based).

I am evaluating if it is possible to package sqlite3-ruby for Windows, Linux and Mac.

My thoughts were, to download sqlite3-amalgamation, sqlite3-ruby on all the platforms and then compile on each.

Here are my questions/current problems:

1) The [sqlite3-ruby docs](http://github.com/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby) on [compiling](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) states:

> Install SQLite3, enabling option `SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA`

Where do I put this? In the makefile? Any pointers or an example would be really helpful!

2) Compiling sqlite3-ruby with the current sqlite3 - sqlite3-ruby seems to search for `sqlite.h`, unfortunately the current sqlite3 seems to only provide `sqlite3.h`; What am I doing wrong here?

Are my thoughts/steps on compiling sqlite3-ruby wrong, maybe?

1. Download amalgamation from sqlite.org
2. Compile to a custom dir
3. Change `install.rb` (line 11) to:

`unless system( "ruby extconf.rb --with-sqlite-dir=/my/custom_dir" )`

Any pointers or help very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

re: windows you can just use the windows precompiled binary gem.

Answer (score 0):

To partially answer a really old question, to enable column meta-data set

`CFLAGS = -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA`

in the Makefile.  By default there is nothing on that line in the Makefile (`CFLAGS =`)

([doc](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_column_metadata))